# При проверке xml с помощью libxml ошибка

Tags: php, xml

Согласно спецификации https://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.xsd

есть пункт `<xs:element name="alternative" type="xs:altType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>`

у меня есть достаточно сложная xsd схема .. 
где присуствуют вот такие строки

```
<xs:element name="property" type="tns:TPhysicalValue">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Физические свойства объекта недвижимости</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:alternative test="@type = 'area'" type="tns:TAreaPhysicalValue"/>
            <xs:alternative test="@type = 'builtypArea'" type="tns:TAreaPhysicalValue"/>
            <xs:alternative test="@type = 'length'" type="tns:TLengthPhysicalValue"/>
            <xs:alternative test="@type = 'height'" type="tns:TLengthPhysicalValue"/>
            <xs:alternative test="@type = 'occurenceDepth'" type="tns:TLengthPhysicalValue"/>
            <xs:alternative test="@value = 'cost'" type="tns:TMoneyPhysicalValue"/>
            <xs:alternative test="@type = 'volume'" type="tns:TVolumePhysicalValue"/>
        </xs:element>
```

однако на строке `<xs:alternative test="@type = 'area'" type="tns:TAreaPhysicalValue"/>`

останавливается вот с такой ошибкой

```
Error 3033: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element': The content is not valid. Expected is (annotation?, ((simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). in /Interdep_v012/TObject.xsd on line 224
```

PHP Version 5.5.24

```
 libxml
libXML support  active
libXML Compiled Version 2.9.0
libXML Loaded Version   20900
libXML streams  enabled

dom
DOM/XML enabled
DOM/XML API Version 20031129
libxml Version  2.9.2
HTML Support    enabled
XPath Support   enabled
XPointer Support    enabled
Schema Support  enabled
RelaxNG Support enabled
```

Сразу говорю - схема с росреестра. 
И вроде бы как не должно в ней быть ошибок ... однако - все сами видите

Comment: Не могли бы вы привести воспроизводимый пример? Минимальный xml документ + php-код в которых эта ошибка воспроизводится.

Comment: вот на просторах стека аналогичная [проблема](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831373/xsd-the-content-is-not-valid) советуют добавить элемент в simpleType `sd:simpleType name="stackOverflowTest"`

Comment: в Вашем случае, думаю, должно быть не `<xs:element` а `<xs:simpleType`. Конечно могу ошибаться

Comment: ради смеха я создал вот такую xml  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><tns:interdepStatement xmlns:tns="http://rosreestr.ru/services/v0.1/TInterdepStatement"/>
а по части создать чтото запускаемое врятли получится - схема из 30 файлов - самое смешное что я даже прямую ссылку на схему дать не могу - могу только кудато выложить

Comment: По логике мне и править то ее не следует - ведь это приходит с вышестоящей организации - неужели они выложили схему с ошибкой .. а нет онлайн ресурса который просто бы проводил валидацию - но сложную ( чтобы эти файлы можно было бы подгружать при необходимости. Просто есть целая куча онлайн валидаторов но они все работает по 1 файлу

Comment: Была идея что это иззатого что я не полную xml использую - сейчас взял готовый их пример xml результат был тот же самый .. значит проблема всетаки не у меня а в схеме.. а ведь именно по этой схеме они проверяют ( по крайней мере должны)

Comment: @Slavka не совсем понял схема чужая а xml Ваш. Так?

Comment: Да, чужая - схема с росреестра ( СМЭВ 3), xml  - у них же есть пример, я взял его полностью и скопировал - для тестирования. результат вы видели. Ради интереса в схеме удалил этот странный блок .. - вроде сдвинулся с мертвой точки - только тут уже другая ошибка выскакивает- позже попробую разобраться

Comment: удалось ли разрешить проблему? Столкнулся с аналогичной бедой, есть ли выход из ситуации не меняя XSD Росреестра?